# Dynamic SQL stored procedure and datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a simple query that I want to convert to dynamic SQL. I have 2 input parameters: a table and a datetime. And the output is the rowcount for the table and this specific datetime.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [etl].[ROWCOUNT_TST2]
    (@P_LOAD_TARGET nvarchar(250),
     @P_LOAD_DATE DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as Inserted FROM'+@P_LOAD_TARGET +' WHERE VALID_FROM ='''+  @P_LOAD_DATE+''' AND VALID_TO IS NULL'

    EXEC  (@SQL)
END;
GO
```

I tried different solutions. I tried the query with execute `sp_executesql`, I tied to add the the ''' before and after the `@P_LOAD_DATE`. I am probably missing something here.

When I execute the stored procedure with a table name and datetime like `2021-05-06 06:41:52.557`, I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But why?

I even tried to add a conversion to datetime like this, but I still get the same error.

```
 SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as Inserted FROM'+@P_LOAD_TARGET +' WHERE VALID_FROM = convert(datetime,'''+  @P_LOAD_DATE+''') AND VALID_TO IS NULL'
```

But when I execute SELECT convert(datetime, '2021-05-06 06:41:52.557') it works out fine. I am just confused right now and can't find the root of the problem.

Edit: `valid_from` is a datetime in the target table. So that is also not the reason for the problem

Comment: Please show your `sp_executesql` attempt. It's most suitable for parameterized dynamic query

Comment: The way to debug dynamic SQL is to `print` it and then run it as static SQL where the errors become obvious.

Comment: I would argue multiple tables with the same column is probably a design smell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to properly and safely inject your dynamic object name and **parametrise** your parameter:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [etl].[ROWCOUNT_TST2](@P_LOAD_SCHEMA sysname = N'dbo', --Always define your schema
                                       @P_LOAD_TARGET sysname, --sysname is the data type for objects, a synonym of nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
                                       @P_LOAD_DATE datetime) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Inserted' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@P_LOAD_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@P_LOAD_TARGET) + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE VALID_FROM = @P_LOAD_DATE' + @CRLF +
               N'  AND VALID_TO IS NULL;';

    --PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@P_LOAD_DATE datetime', @P_LOAD_DATE;

END;
```

Comment: Personally not a fan of `@CRLF` I just put in newlines in the text

Comment: [Why I define my Carriage Returns and Line Breaks as variables in Dynamic SQL](https://wp.larnu.uk/why-i-declare-my-carriage-returns-and-line-breaks-in-dynamic-sql/) @Charlieface . They are there for a *good* reason.

Comment: Not so keen on your arguments: 1. The `13` parameter in `STUFF` should have been calculated dynamically off the separator text. 2. I don't indent the dynamic part at all (relative to the static part), that way I can quite clearly see static-side what is the dynamic part, and the final dynamic query is still formatted correctly

Comment: This is, at best, a different of opinion. I personally, hate random blocks of text that aren't aligned to the rest, @Charlieface , so I am not keen on your point number 2 *"I don't indent the dynamic part at all"*.